# How to ignore 401 error code in Excel Add-in?

Tags: office365, office-js

Identity provider we use/SAML returns the first response as 401 as it is trying to authenticate certain resources internally. When I try to do the same through browser, it ignores the 401 error and goes on to next request and displays the login page.
However in Excel Add-in, it stops there and returns the following error :

App navigation error
The Error code is HTTP_STATUS_DENIED (401)
P1: Apps for Office
P2: 16.0.8431.2046
P3: 0x191
P4:

Add-in Error
A problem occurred while trying to reach this add-in.
P1: Apps for Office
P2: 16.0.8431.2046
P3: 0x191
P4:

Is there any way we can ignore the initial 401 error in Excel Add-in same like browser?

Comment: Please provide some more context and detail. I don't know what you mean by "SSO url".

Comment: We are using SAML/ Identity Provider for authentication.

Comment: Can someone please help on this?

Comment: I need a LOT more context to understand your question. What is the chain of user actions that leads up to the error? What do you mean by "first response" and "next request"? What do you mean by "authenticate ... internally"?